# How do I setup report in SSRS to be viewed in HTML and PDF Outputs, within a single .rdl?

Tags: html, reporting-services

I need help figuring out how to setup report in SSRS to be viewed in HTML and PDF Outputs, within a single .rdl.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if you build a report, in most cases, you can export it to PDF without any real issues.

However, not all renderers support all circumstances so you might need to lookup the differences between the default HTML renderer and the PDF renderer. It's usually the following that cause issues.

- Custom Fonts
- Overlapping objects such as having text over an image
- Page size and margins
- Resolution of any images you might want to use in the report.

There will be others too that I can't think of but I suggest you build the report step by step and test each significant bit of work by exporting to PDF and checking the results.